# Finding the label of an input field in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a form where each text box has a title. I already have the WebElement of the text boxes, and I want to reference their title (the title that has `"for=id"` pointing to them).

I've tried their `getText` which only returns the text in the input box, tried `getCssValue("label")` which doesn't return with anything. I've tried finding all the labels but that doesn't help as I'd still have to sift through all of them, and find the 8 different labels that need to have the *.

```
<label for="customer_firstname">First name <sup>*</sup></label>
<input onkeyup="$('#firstname').val(this.value);" type="text" class="is_required validate form-control" data-validate="isName" id="customer_firstname" name="customer_firstname" value="">
```

I want to get back a string of the label text so I can check `(with .contains())`if it contains the `"*"`at the end. Preferably with as little Xpath as possible.

Answer (score 1):

to indicate label tag using input tag, you can use this xpath :

```
//input[@id='customer_firstname']/preceding-sibling::label
```

if you just want input field then you should use id which I think is unique in your case, though you will have to verify this in DOM.

```
id = customer_firstname
```

For referencing with `<label **for**>`

you can use this code :

```
String  custLabelAttribute = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='customer_firstname']/preceding-sibling::label")).getAttribute("for")
```

this should print : **customer_firstname**

Comment: Is there no way to reference the label from the WebElement of the input field?

Comment: yes, you can , label is just preceding-sibling of input tag (They belong to same family). Try the given xpath . Let me know for any more concerns.

Answer (score 0):

if both Input and label tags are belongs from same parent then you can take first unique xpath of parents and then adding // you can reach up to the label tag and get text.  you should reach up to label tag by find unique xpath and use .gettext() then u will get innertext of label tag.